# How to approach documentation translation for an open source project?

Tags: open-source

I'm going to start a little open source project with some friends from all over the world. As I know that one of most important things in open source projects is to help users use the project itself, I want to make some wiki/tutorials/whatever in different languages.

What are best tools or way to think/act in general for managing translations? Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try and find a way of rewarding people who put the effort into doing the translation. Maybe credits on the software, or privileges, like there are on this site. Accept translations freely, like with a wiki, but try and get them reviewed by someone who speaks the same language fluently.